# having resultset want to split the xml file into multiple xml files, if file size exceed 1 MB in java

Tags: java

I have an resultset and all records are write in one xml file(using Marshaller via JAXBContext with file encoding ISO-8859-1). I want to split the xml file into multiple xml files, if file size exceed 1 MB. so this need to be done within while loop, when it reaches 1 MB, I need to create another file. 
so here what will be the correct approach I tried with 
getting object size using Instrumentation(java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation) but object size and file size is different.

Comment: Please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Just dropping requirements "this is what I want" isn't appreciated. When you try something yourself, and you get stuck with a specific problem, we will gladly help. But please understand that this place is not intended to give guidance with the possibly many steps required to get you from your vision to a working program.

Comment: Provide a code in the form of a [minimal reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example please. Right now I can't guess what to recommend.